# Is there a video editor or screencast tool for Android with good blurring/censoring feature?

Tags: android, video-editing, screen-recording

There a lot of different apps, but, I guess, almost all of them lack of blurring/censoring feature for certain frames (not the whole video like in "Blur Video" app, for example). Or am I missing something? Ideally, I want a good screencast/video editing app for software testing (QA/QC) purposes, but I don't want to include some private info in my test videos.